# Cannot get FB.ui Method:oauth to work

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph, facebook-oauth, fb.ui

I've been battling with this all morning.

I'm actually trying to get custom Open Graph Actions to work. I've succeeded in this, piecing together bits of information from here and there and everywhere, and now I have a button which posts a "Want" action with the following flow:

```
> User Clicks Button
> FB.api checks response.
    > if response code is 200 the user has not granted publish_stream permission
        > call FB.ui({ method:
                  "permissions.request",
                  "perms": 'email,publish_stream'
                }
        > call back to original function and post to stream
    > if user has already granted permission, then just publish
```

That all works lovely.

What I need though, is to catch a case where the user is not logged in to Facebook at all.

This appears to be response code `2500` where no access token is present

SO I have this code snippe, which catches that case

```
.....
} else if (((response.error.code) * 1) == 2500) {
    doLogin('publish_stream', postWant, itemId); 
    // post want being the original function and itemId being the item we are "wanting"
}
```

my doLogin function looks like this:

```
    function doLogin(permRequired, callingFunction, urlAppend) {
        FB.ui({ 
            method: 'oauth', 
            scope: 'email,' + permRequired
        },
        function (response) {
            // DO THINGS NOW WE'RE LOGGED IN
        });
    };
```

This is basically exactly the same as my function to get the extended permission, which looks like this:

```
    function getPermission(permRequired, callingFunction, urlAppend) {
        FB.ui({ method:
            "permissions.request",
            "perms": 'email,' + permRequired
        },
        function (response) {
            // DO THINGS NOW WE HAVE PERMISSION
        });
    };
```

This latter example WORKS, but the Login example just loads a popup saying "Sorry, something went wrong, please try again later"

Obviously FB.init is already called, the APP is set up correctly, APP_ID declared in FB.init and so on, clearly, as the other stuff works.

FB Login froma  FB Login button works, but I need this to work through this flow in order for the "frictionless" behaviour to operate (ie, I can't have another button to click)

Answer (score 1):

Don’t use FB.ui with method:"permissions.request" – just use FB.login, and set the options parameter with the scope of (additional) permissions you require.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/